# Host and serve “Hello World”

Tags: google-drive-api

https://googledrive.com/host/0B1LVOoV_2dFtTnNOVWdZcWpqaWs/index.html

Above is the link to my “Hello World” file which, sadly, fails to render as HTML.

What’s weird is, the HTML source code of that page is the same as what renders (i.e., all HTML tags are visible)? I have never seen that before.

I know it's something extremely basic, but what am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

I did remember to store my publicly shared “published on the web” index.html file inside a publicly shared “published on the web” folder with ID/index 0B1LVOoV_2dFtTnNOVWdZcWpqaWs (as taken from the URL when viewing the folder in drive. i.e., The URL is: https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0&pli=1#folders/0B1LVOoV_2dFtTnNOVWdZcWpqaWs)

However, I did not use any “webViewLink” nor would I know what to do with that? I tried somehow jamming it into the browser address bar before the URL but that didn’t work. So how do I use it?

Again, What am I overlooking? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create the file and later renamed the extension? If so its file type might be wrong. Check that on file properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zig Mandel was correct. I had originally uploaded my file as a .js and later changed it to .html. The reason I did this was as a workaround because Google Drive was automatically converting my .html file to a Google Doc.

After reading [this](http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2013/02/google-drive-site-hosting.html) post (paragraph two, last sentence), it occurred to me there is a setting in Google Drive that allows one to turn off the automatic conversion. (However, you have to upload a file to see the automatic conversion option if you have automatic checking turned off.)

So the answer is that you must upload the file as an .html file. If you are getting a Google Doc after you upload, then turn off the automatic conversion option provided by Google Drive during upload.